# intersection of union of events

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we reduce $$ \cap_{i>0} \cup_{j\geq i} A_j $$ to events with just intersections like $$ \cap_{k} A_k ~?$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No

Suppose $A_i = \{1,2,\ldots, i\}$

Then $\bigcup\limits_{j \ge i} A_j = \mathbb N^+$

and so $\bigcap\limits_{i \gt 0} \bigcup\limits_{j \ge i} A_j = \mathbb N^+$

but $\bigcap\limits_{k \gt 0}  A_k = \{1\}$, which is rather smaller

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not in an especially helpful way.

The event $\bigcap_{i> 0}\bigcup_{j\ge i}A_i$ is equal to the event that there are infinitely many $i$ for which $A_i$ occurs. This means there is at least one infinite sequence $i(1)<i(2)<i(3)\dots$ for which $A_{i(j)}$ all occur. Therefore, you can write $\bigcap_{i\ge 0}\bigcup_{j\ge i}A_i$ as the infinite union over all such sequences of the intersection of the $A_{i(j)}$. 
$$
\bigcap_{i>0}\bigcup_{j\ge i}A_i=\bigcup_{i(1)<i(2)<\dots}\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty A_{i(j)}
$$
This is an uncountable union of events, so it is not too useful.